# BitmapFactory cannot decode a CipherInputStream twice

Tags: android, image, encryption

I encrypt, then decrypt an image that I then pass to my image util for resizing, (code graciously borrowed from somewhere) like so:

```
public static Bitmap loadResizedBitmap(InputStream dis, int width, int height) {

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(dis);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, options);
    if (options.outHeight > 0 && options.outWidth > 0) {
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 2;

        while (options.outWidth / options.inSampleSize > width && 
                options.outHeight / options.inSampleSize > height) {
            options.inSampleSize++;
        }
        options.inSampleSize--;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, options);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

The issue is during the second **decodeStream**, the BitmapFactory returns **null**. I have verified the first one works, and outputs the correct size, etc. My guess is that CipherInputStream does not support mark and reset, so I wrapped it in a BufferedInputStream with no luck. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ANSWERED]

I switched it to use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray and that solved it. I took another look at the API and I was able to pass along a byte[].

My takeaway is CipherInputStream does not support mark() and reset().